# How to move the inscription vertical line down in chartjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, graphics, chart.js

There is a plotted chartjs chart, and through prototype.draw a vertical line is drawn. How to move the text of the vertical lines down, if it goes beyond the canvas and is not displayed?

```
Chart.elements.Line.prototype.draw = function () {
    this._chart.ctx.save();
    this._chart.ctx.strokeStyle = '#808080';

    var points = this._chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data,
        point_x = points[points.length - 1]._model.x,
        point_y = points[points.length - 1]._model.y,
        bottom = this._chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom;

    this._chart.ctx.beginPath();
    this._chart.ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    this._chart.ctx.moveTo(point_x, point_y);
    this._chart.ctx.lineTo(point_x, bottom);

    this._chart.ctx.textAlign = 'right';
    this._chart.ctx.fillStyle = '#808080';
    if ($(window).width() < 420) {
        this._chart.ctx.font = '500 14px "Montserrat", sans-serif';
        this._chart.ctx.fillText("Payback", point_x - 2, bottom - 14);
    } else {
        this._chart.ctx.font = '500 16px "Montserrat", sans-serif';
        this._chart.ctx.fillText("Payback", point_x - 5, bottom + 24);
    }

    this._chart.ctx.stroke();
    this._chart.ctx.restore();
}
```

[chart preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AXwX.png)

[need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjoHP.png)